# Где найти ресурсы для изучения темы обфускации именно данных, что-то из ASCII, UTF-8 или бинарных

Tags: javascript, криптография, reverse

Требуется именно обфускация данных, будь это строки или двоичные, язык кода не важен, но желательно с реализацией на фронте (js). К сожалению, по запросу гуглятся только обфускаторы кода, для данных никак найти не могу.

Заинтересовала тема после участия на CTF, где был код обфускатора на JS и требовалось зареверсить и написать деобфускатор ([ссылка на код решения](https://github.com/Dead4W/student_ctf_js_deobfuscate/blob/main/test.js)).

Хочу увидеть полезные практики и методы и попробовать написать реализацию своего для практики, одна из идей использовать XOR ГПЧ, сид брать из session_hash или user_id.

Пойдет всё, книги, статьи, код.

Спасибо за любую важную инфу!

Comment: Обфускация _кода_ затрудняет разбор этого кода _человеком_. Но код при этом продолжает работать - это ключевой момент. Обфускация _данных_ не нужна, потому что данные сами по себе не работают - их берёт _код_ и использует. Поэтому данные _шифруем_. То есть используем любой алгоритм криптования. Если речь о вебе, то использование протокола https сделает всё за вас.

Comment: Меня интересует эта тема в плане сокрытия данных и затруднение для ботов или просмотра того или иного контента. Такие алгоритмы не редкость, их применяют, к примеру, для чтения книг или проверки лицензии вместе с шифрованием. Понятно, что чистая обфускация не панацея. Также полезно применять обфускацию с хешем, так подделать запрос сложнее, не зная как работает хеш и проблемотичнее разобрать без реверса